# Как создать сетевое web-приложение?

Tags: веб-программирование, apache, веб-сервер

Хочу создать сетевое веб-приложение (не глобальное!). Использую сервер `Apache`. Компьютеры соединены в домашнюю сеть, естественно, один ПК как сервер. На нем, допустим, есть сайт `mysite.loc`. Как зайти на него через веб-браузер, с другого ПК в сети? Зайти как на сайт, а не как на папку с файлами! Возможно, как-то по-своему надо настроить `apache` и `hosts`? Сейчас, когда я ввожу `mysite.loc` (не на сервере), ничего не получается, пишется файл не найден (в общем, нет такого сайта).

Comment: Если я правильно понял то, в файле hosts на машине с которой идете (не на сервере), пишите ip вашего сервера mysite.loc.т.е строка например: 192.168.0.10 mysite.loc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Примерно такой конфиг апача (надо, чтоб файлик лежал в `sites-enabled` с именем `mysite.loc`):

```
<VirtualHost mysite.loc:80>          ServerAdmin webmaster@mysite.loc          ServerName mysite.loc:80        DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite.loc        <Directory />                Options FollowSymLinks                AllowOverride All        </Directory>        <Directory /var/www/>                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews                AllowOverride All                Order allow,deny                allow from all        </Directory>        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">                AllowOverride All                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch                Order allow,deny                Allow from all        </Directory>        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,        # alert, emerg.        LogLevel warn        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks        AllowOverride All        Order deny,allow        Deny from all        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128    </Directory></VirtualHost>
```

В `ports.conf` (апачевский) пишем:

```
NameVirtualHost mysite.loc:80Listen 80
```

В /etc/hosts добавляем:

```
<ip сервера> mysite.loc <имя сервера>
```

Сам сайт кидаем в /var/www/mysite.loc/

На клиентской машине правим `hosts` как сказал [[@pyatak](/users/814/pyatak)](/users/814/pyatak).Указанное выше справедливо для linux'а (на ubunte-server опробовано :))

Comment: И еще конфиг ядра на всякий случай)

Comment: а если абстрагироваться от Linux, на 7-ках вроде ничего экстра менять не надо в конфиге свыше?

Comment: "а если абстрагироваться от Linux, на 7-ках вроде ничего экстра менять не надо в конфиге свыше?"На каких семерках? У Вас поднято что-то типа WAMP'а? Или речь о клиентских машинах?

Comment: поднято mysql+php+apache+phpmyadmin, я не знаю как это назвать, поднято на 7-ке.